# How to fix 'Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - /home/admin/project/spec/mailers)' Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, debian, puma

The server is debian, using nginx web server. I see the logs, the error is because no file or directory. I don't understand. Please help!

It was good before but the I restarted my server and then cannot show the error page:
[image]

Here is the log:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - /home/admin/project/spec/mailers):

listen (3.1.5) lib/listen/adapter/config.rb:17:in `realpath'
listen (3.1.5) lib/listen/adapter/config.rb:17:in `realpath'
listen (3.1.5) lib/listen/adapter/config.rb:17:in `block in initialize'
listen (3.1.5) lib/listen/adapter/config.rb:16:in `map'
listen (3.1.5) lib/listen/adapter/config.rb:16:in `initialize'
listen (3.1.5) lib/listen/backend.rb:25:in `new'
listen (3.1.5) lib/listen/backend.rb:25:in `initialize'
listen (3.1.5) lib/listen/listener.rb:47:in `new'
listen (3.1.5) lib/listen/listener.rb:47:in `initialize'
listen (3.1.5) lib/listen.rb:41:in `new'
listen (3.1.5) lib/listen.rb:41:in `to'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/evented_file_update_checker.rb:96:in `boot!'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/evented_file_update_checker.rb:73:in `block in updated?'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/evented_file_update_checker.rb:71:in `synchronize'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/evented_file_update_checker.rb:71:in `updated?'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:159:in `map'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:159:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Finisher>'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/reloader.rb:81:in `check!'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/reloader.rb:63:in `run!'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:22:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
webpacker (3.6.0) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:22:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:660:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:474:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Do you require somewhere in your application `spec/mailer` ?

Comment: i have no idea, how can i find it out?
but i found this in nginx error logs
```
unix:/home/admin/elxr/shared/sockets/puma.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream
```